# Vertical full Page Slider like www.tumblr.com in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, fullpage.js

I am looking to implement a full page slider on the home page of my app(made with Angular 1.x)

I have tried couple of libraries, but to no avail. They seem to have incomplete instructions or not full proof bug-wise

Here are the ones I tried.

https://github.com/lukesnowden/FSVS

https://github.com/hellsan631/angular-fullpage.js

Example of what I am trying to achieve is www.tumblr.com home page. If I scroll up or down the slider, the pages change with different content.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My library [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) creates exactly the same effect than tumblr home page.

Doing it with angular or not should be irrelevant. Just do no use `anchors` in the URL and initialize it only once, and you should be fine with it.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. How is it different than fullpage.js. From first look, it looks quite similar. I am going to give it a try. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Just pay attention to the animation. This is not a scrolling animation, is one layer over another.

Comment: This is quiet neat. big difference from fullpage.js. In all just more appealing. Huge Inc got something similar but with subtle differences and I wondered how they achieved it. Thanks for this. Excited to try it out.

Comment: @ViditSaxena [I wrote an article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/04/09/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/) about it. But be advised, the last section won't scroll on mobile devices.

Comment: Great article, The navigation bullets are getting doubled every time I go to the link where I have piling. It's may because the angular controller is loaded again. Have you seen that problem? Other wise, everything else if working like a charm. Here is a fiddle of my javascript https://jsfiddle.net/viditsaxena/objhkdnh/